# qTip returns error "Object has no method 'qtip'"

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I am using the following code from another thread and, for an unknown reason, I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'qtip'

Code:

```
$('.tooltip').each(function(){
   $(this).qtip({
      content: {text: $('#helptext_' + $(this).attr('id'))},
      style: {classes: 'ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-rounded'},
      position: {my: 'left center',at: 'right center', viewport: $(window)}
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call the `qtip.js` (or whatever) before you call that function, otherwise it won't be loaded by the time this code runs.

Comment: Thanks to all that replied. I in actual fact did have the qTip.js call inside my code but it looks like that I had a duplicate of it, which caused me the issue. Removed the duplicate and all is now fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1)  Go here and download the qTip2 package...

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download/

2)  Then add this to your `<head>` section...

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/your/path/jquery.qtip.css" />
```

3)  Add this qTip script includes someplace just **after** your jQuery includes...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/your/path/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I started to work with qtip, I have used the following code to check if the qtip is assigned to the element:

```
if (DOM_element.qtip) { //wrong
    .....
}
```

which is the wrong way. When I got more familiar with jquery I've corrected my mistake.

The right way to check if there is any qtip connected to the element is:

```
if ($(DOM_element).data('qtip')) { //right
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a typo in mine (`<scrpt> instead of <script>`), but I also used this to remove any potential conflicts with other scripts:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

You can learn more about it here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries